# space at the bottom of my page

Tags: css, space

For some reason on my website there is space at the bottom, I have tried to set the height of wrapper but that didnt change anything... I was hoping someone on here could give me a hand, I still have alot to learn so please be nice! :D

Thanks

link: [propertytest.uphero.com](http://propertytest.uphero.com)

Comment: This is only a chrome issue?  looks OK in ie9 for me.  I think that chrome is being more sensitive to the validation problems against the doc-type.  The fix below will work (well it does for me by injecting the CSS) but imho is that it is just a band-aid.  Get to valid HTML and then track down the route cause of the issue.  Sorry W3C validator - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpropertytest.uphero.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Wow.Lots of junky code. I'm tired.  I Giveup. Stop positioning all the blocks using 'relative' .

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your html and body tag to 100% (in CSS)

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @ngen: I did that in chrome and the extra space at the bottom dissapears

Comment: i guess your code will make it alright in chrome. but not in firefox.

Comment: indeed I did not test with firefox. Now I did and you're right. it works in chrome but not firefox. In both of them I can see that the computed body height is only 147px. I think in there you will find your issue

Comment: That's because he has positioned everything using `relative`. !!. murder.

Comment: @PeterAllen  start typing HTML using notepad.  if you are using  an editor. you aren't learning.  Oh . Yes you are using an editor.

Comment: I give up. lots of  markup with relative . i can't edit them all to fix it up.

Comment: @ngen I coded everything just like I would using notepad. Should I be using absolute positioning instead of relative?

Comment: There is no need of  absolute/relative position for that block layout of propertynews - use float: left; with proper width.    then for each ul boxes use float left; and for ul li as well. footer with clear:both; ... basically, summary is : you don't need to  position anything absolutely or relatively.  That  method is not at all good .

Answer (score 0):

First thing first,

Cleanup that  piece of code after `</html>` .

Do everything within `</body>` .

Then, Clear up the  floats before the last div by using `<p style="clear:both;height:0;">&nbsp;</p>` . You are not supposed to leave any tailed floats.

Comment: Chrome (19.x) is doing this automatically. When opening the developer tools you can see the code has moved to just before the     </body> tag

Comment: @barts , that's because he moved it now. No browser moves the markup!.

Comment: I cleared cache, reloade the page and see that it did not move at all. In developer tools it still shows the lines before the body closing tag

Comment: @VivekChandra Will you allow me to edit!. I'm checking the page and he is changing it as well on the fly!.

Comment: @barts i think that code is being added by the hosting co:. Anyways that's not causing the issue.